# Solr-Filter on Json Facet aggregation

Tags: apache, solr

I have a use case where i would need to filter in the aggregated value from the facet.

Does facet filter allow that?

**Example:**
Getting the sum of a number field that are greater than 0 grouping by country

So my Jason facet would look like

```
json.facet={cty:{type:terms,field:country,facet:{sum_value:”sum(population)”}}}
```

In the above request I need to add a filter to return only those cty buckets where `sum_value is >100`

Answer (score 0):

Well, we have faced the similar task before, and I would say that there is no way Solr can filter calculated values. Either you can fetch all the facet by setting limit equal to -1 and then there will be some wrapper(WEB API) you need to write over your search application which will filter the facet list.

```
json.facet={cty:{type:terms,field:country,limit:-1,facet:{sum_value:”sum(population)”}}}
```

Or you can Pre-calculate the sum of population for each country before indexing. Look at the below table.

|Country|Population| Total_Population|

| C1 | 12 | 25  |
| C1 | 13 | 25  |
| C2 | 14 | 49  |
| C2 | 35 | 49  |

Later on, you can directly filter on Total_Population field by using filter query. Also, you will be saving lot of time by not doing aggregations in real time.

Answer (score 0):

Solr supports sorting facets by nested functions. You can sort based on your facet and limit the response. For your use case:

```
json.facet={
cty:{
    type:terms,
    field:country,
    sort: "sum_value desc"
    facet:
        {
            sum_value:”sum(population)”
        }
    }
}
```

Also you can pass limit=100 to filter out top 100 sum_value

[Source](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_5/json-facet-api.html#sorting-facets-by-nested-functions)